# Matplotlib pyplot: How to plot multiple trends in different areas of the plot?

Tags: time-series, matplotlib

I am trying plot some trends using matplotlib.pyplot. The task is straightforward, but there is *one* detail I can't get right. I wish to plot a numpy.array called `trend`, that is of a given length. I have two other trends representing the prediction intervals, called `PI_high` and `PI_low`. I wish to plot them as a continuation of `trend`.

`trend` is of length 60, therefore I wish to plot trend on the 0:60 x-axis. While `PI_high` and `PI_low` are of length 12 and shall be plotted on the 60:72 x-axis. However, when I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(trend)
plt.plot(PI_high)
plt.plot(PI_low)
plt.show()
```

The prediction interval is displayed at the very beginning of the plot (i.e. on 0:12 x-axis). How can I make it start more forward on the x-axis, on the segment that I want?